# Asp.net users table password hash field problem

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

Some of the users in an asp.net core with Identity after registering i see some html tag in password hash field of AspNetUsers table. And those users when try to log in getting an empty screen, when i tested on my local pc i see the error incorrect syntax for password sha hash or something like that. After i checked the table the password hash of some users were

AAQSKFKDLsjk;;l;l;u6XpbAbPJomtBKX0E51H/OLNmjYTM3dZvo4B9sR5g==vioft2nntf|0000D4D1CD99|konsbasvuru|AspNetUsers|PasswordHash

It's always the same html code after their hash "vioft2nntf|0000D4D1CD99|konsbasvuru|AspNetUsers|PasswordHash"

i got rid of it by splitting it with == as seperator and removing the tag and adding == again.

I could not find any problems in the code. What can it be. Security issues or bug?

Could not find any answer on the net. Checked Microsoft and .Net forums too. Even ChatGPT did not give me a satisfactory answer.

[image]

Comment: this code starting with vioftnntf is in a div tag with style display none btw

Comment: We would need to see some code to be of much assistance.  My guess is your missing a closing tag somewhere and it's pulling the next field in as part of the value submitted.